# Change deployment for bosh (using bosh-lite) and CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am using bosh-lite to try out cloud foundry. I have two deployments:

```
$ bosh deployments

+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Name                | Release(s)            | Stemcell(s)                                     |
+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| cf-services-contrib | cf-services-contrib/6 | bosh-warden-boshlite-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent/389 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| cf-warden           | cf/203                | bosh-warden-boshlite-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent/389 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Each of these deployments contains several virtual machines (as can be seen by `bosh vms`).

The current deployment is set the following:

```
$ bosh deployment
Current deployment is `[...]/cf-services-contrib-release/tmp/contrib-services-warden-manifest.yml'
```

I can ssh into vms in that selected deployment with the command `bosh ssh`, but I cannot ssh into any other vm. How do I change the selected deployment?

I tried `bosh deployment cf/203`, and also by passing the absolute path to the cf-release/releases/cf-203.yml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latter suggestion should work:

```
bosh deployment path/to/manifest.yml
bosh ssh
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works. Yet it seems complicated to first do a `cf download manifest <deployment> <filename.yml>`, then do a `cf deployment filename.yml` to finally ssh into one of the vms. Is there a faster way?